# SecurityContextLogoutHandler testing problem

Tags: junit, spring-security, mockito, spring-test

Is there any way to test this using JUnit and Mockito?

Below is a method that I want to test

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String logoutPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (auth != null)
        {
            new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
        }
        return "redirect:/login?logout";
    }
```

Test for logout

```
@Test
    public void testLogoutPage() throws Exception
    {
        MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = get("/logout");
        MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(this.loginController)
                .build()
                .perform(requestBuilder)
                .andExpect(status().isFound())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().size(0))
                .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/login?logout"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.redirectedUrl("/login?logout"));
    }
```

Test covers everything except.

```
 new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
```

I tried some assertions, but always get NullPointerException.

Comment: I edited question, so now you can see the whole method.
Below is my test code for logout page

Answer (score 0):

You can test that you were logged out by adding unauthenticated() to your expect chain.

*Libs: JUnit 5 and Spring Boot 2.7.1*

```
@Test
public void testLogoutPage() throws Exception
{
    MockHttpServletRequestBuilder requestBuilder = get("/logout");
    MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(this.loginController)
            .build()
            .perform(requestBuilder)
            .andExpect(unauthenticated()) // Added
            .andExpect(status().isFound())
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().size(0))
            .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/login?logout"))
            .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.redirectedUrl("/login?logout"));
}
```